# How to set align 64 in ml64.exe?

Tags: assembly, x86, alignment, masm, segments

What is a simplest way to set `align 64` for some assembler function code with `ml64.exe`?
Default alignment for `_TEXT` is 16, so `ml64` doesn't allow to set more than 16 in `align` command.
And `ml64` doesn't allow to change alignment for `_TEXT`.

It's possible to create another section/segment, but can we get `64 byte` alignment in main `_TEXT` section?

Is there any solution?

P.S.
Solution suggested in answer with `_TEXT$FOO` works!

`_TEXT$FOO SEGMENT ALIGN(64)
align 64
_TEXT$FOO ENDS`

I also tried to change the value in alignment field in `Characteristics` in section header for `_TEXT` in obj (coff) file in hex editor. And the linker used that changed alignment. So why ml and jwasm don't allow to change that default 16 bytes for `_TEXT`, if linker can use any value from that field in obj file?

64-byte alignment is useful for code in some cases.
If you use 16-bytes alignment, then another code (it can be `C` code) can randomly move your `asm` code for 4 different offsets: 0, 16, 32, 48.
And some loops probably can cross 64-bytes or 32-bytes range. So you can see some unpredictable changes of performance of `asm` code , when you just change another `C` code.

Comment: That's weird.  On Linux with NASM or YASM creating ELF object files, the largest alignment requirement in a section becomes the alignment requirement for that section.  (And thus for the segment after linking.)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by 64-byte alignment of the _TEXT section? I smell a possible XY problem here. Placing a function on a cache line?

Comment: How about `ALIGN 64` before the procedure definition? Like `ALIGN 64` `test_proc PROC` `...` `ret` `test_proc ENDP`? You don't need to change alignment of section itself, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwa9fwef.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it should align also next instruction. (I guess your "align command" is meant as the attribute of _TEXT section)

Comment: Maybe there is a another directive which sets the section alignment? That's how the `ALIGN` directive in `nasm` works: it has  a local effect in aligning the next emitted byte, [but it also calls `SECTALIGN` so the whole section has at least that alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904324/149138).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, apparently `ml64` (Microsoft Macro Assembler (x64)) doesn't let you change the alignment of the `.text` section, so you can't have anything in it with an alignment bigger than 16 bytes. However, there's a simple workaround for this problem and that's to use PECOFF's grouped sections feature. If a section has a dollar sign `$` in its name then everything after the `$` is ignored when linking, so that all sections with the same prefix before the `$` are merged into one section. The merged sections are sorted by the full section name, including what comes after the `$`.

So for example you can do:

```
_TEXT$FOO SEGMENT ALIGN(64)
    int 3

    ALIGN   64
    PUBLIC  function
function:
    ret

_TEXT$FOO ENDS

_TEXT   SEGMENT
    PUBLIC  start
start:
    call function
    int 3
_TEXT   ENDS

    END
```

In the example above the `_TEXT` and `_TEXT$FOO` sections will be merged into one `.text` section by the linker.  The code in `_TEXT$FOO` will come after the the code in `_TEXT`.

Note that if you're really trying to align readonly data, not actual code, then you should put the data in the `.rdata` section instead.  Something like this:

```
_RDATA  SEGMENT ALIGN(64) ALIAS(".rdata") READONLY
    DB  1h

    ALIGN   64
    PUBLIC  readonlydata
readonlydata:
    DB  0ffh
_RDATA  ENDS
```

Note that you have to use the `ALIAS(".rdata")` option here because the assembler doesn't automatically translate `_RDATA` into `.rdata` the same way it translates `_TEXT` and `_DATA` into `.text` and `.data`.